# Want to buy wind speed sensor, small, cheap

Tags: meteorology, wind

I want to build a small atmospheric sensor setup that will include an anemometer. It doesn't have to be especially accurate but should be small, lightweight and reliable. The part I'm missing is the wind cups and its interface to the Pi, I've got the directional stuff figured. Any leads on where I might shop?

Comment: eBay used auction?

Comment: "Vaavud" is a wind measuring device for smartphones. It is plugged into the 3.5 mm audio jack. It is not too expensive. Not sure how it works. Maybe you can connect it somehow to your Raspberry Pi. With "*Pi*" your probably mean Raspberry Pi?

Comment: thanks Daniel, it looks great so far, I'll get in touch with them!